# Difference between `.click(handler())` and `.click(handler)`

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function myFun()
    {
        alert(5)
    }
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#myID").click(myFun());
        })
    </script>
 </head>

 <body>
  <input type="button" value="Click it" id="myID" />
 </body>
</html>
```

When I run this code then `alert(5)` is coming when the page loads. If I write

```
$("#myID").click(myFun)
```

then the alert only appears when we click on the button. Why does it behave like this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Functions might be helpful to understand functions better.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$("#myID").click(myFun());
```

This calls `myFun()` and tries to install whatever it returns as an event handler. Since it is not returning anything, you are actually *triggering* the click on `#myID`.

Comment: @Lanzz.. if you see my entire question, I also called function as you mentioned. But what is the difference. Suppose if I want to pass any arguments then how to do it?

Comment: `$("#myID").click(function() { myFun(some, arguments) });`

Comment: when you pass the function() it means you intend to call that method, if you don't then it will be called only when actually click event is fired.

Answer (score 3):

Read this [.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/) - Bind an event handler to the `click` JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element using JavaScript.

You just need to write `$("#myID").click(myFun);` instead of `$("#myID").click(myFun());` because when you write `myFun()` in your code the function is invoked immediately (rather than when a click event fires on `#myID`).

## Working  Demo

Answer (score 2):

Try this for running the function on the click event:

```
function myFun(){
    alert(5);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myID").click(function(){
        myFun();
    });
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

This will work

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function myFun() {
        alert(5)
    }
            $("#myID").click(function(){
            myFun();
            });
});​
```