# $(document).ready() handler fires immediately

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've made a small page that just has this as the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<title>hi</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" href="js/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom/css/black-tie/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.css" rel="Stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.js"></script>

<link type="text/css" href="css/main.css" rel="Stylesheet" />
<script src="js/main.js"></script>

<script>
    $(main());
/* or $(document).ready(main()); */
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="loginDiv" class="popupDiv">
    <div id="usernameDiv">
        <label for="username">username</label>
        <input type="text" id="username"/>
    </div>
    <div id="passwordDiv">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="password"/>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="introDiv">
    <div class="headerDiv">
        <button id="loginButton">Login</button>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And then I have my main.js:

```
function main()
{
    var $loginButton = $('#loginButton');
    var $loginDiv = $('#loginDiv');

    $loginDiv.dialog({ autoOpen: false });

    $loginButton.click(function() {
        $loginDiv.dialog("open");
        //alert('sfsdf');
    });
}
```

I can trigger alerts, but selectors will not return any elements if the .ready() handler is specified in the head.

I have tried moving it to the end of the body tag and everything works fine. According to the [JQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/ready/), the entire DOM and all images and resources are supposed to be loaded before the handler gets called. What gives?

- Firefox 16.0.2 on Linux x86
- JQuery 1.8.2
- JQuery UI 1.9.2 (not really used for the purposes here)

Comment: Same idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10947786/difference-between-clickhandler-and-clickhandler ,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102413/why-does-click-event-handler-fire-immediately-upon-page-load (and many more)

Comment: Yup, but had I known that was the problem in the first place, I would have found those.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you are calling your function!

```
$(main());   <--() means run it
```

You want to assign a reference to it

```
$(main);  <-- no ()!
```

Comment: Ugh. Would you believe I do this for a living?

Comment: Step away from the keyboard grasshopper.

Comment: @Nick I think he means to step back and take another look. A fresh set of eyes can mean a massive difference. To your credit, I didn't notice the error immediately.